# How to handle deeplinking in Flutter using routes

Tags: flutter, deep-linking, navigator

I'm attempting to build deeplink functionality and so far the initial start of the app and retrieving parameters from the deeplink is going fine.

However I am having issues navigating to a screen after I deeplink into the app. How should I do this?

My code looks like this:

```
void main() { 
    runApp(MyApp()); 
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {   
    @override   
    _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState(); 
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {   
   Uri _latestUri;  
   Object _err;

  StreamSubscription _sub;

  @override   void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _handleIncomingLinks();
  }

  @override void dispose() {
    _sub?.cancel();
    super.dispose();   
  }

  void _handleIncomingLinks() {
    _sub = uriLinkStream.listen((Uri uri) {
      if (!mounted) return;
      print('got uri: $uri'); // printed: got uri: myapp://?key1=test
      setState(() {
        _latestUri = uri;
        _err = null;

        Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'login'); // This doesn't work because the context does not include navigator
      });
    }, onError: (Object err) {
      if (!mounted) return;
      print('got err: $err');
      setState(() {
        _latestUri = null;
        if (err is FormatException) {
          _err = err;
        } else {
          _err = null;
        }
      });
    });   
  }

  @override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
          initialRoute: 'splash-screen',
          onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
            switch (settings.name) {
              case 'splash-screen':
                return
                  PageTransition(
                        child: BlocProvider(
                          create: (context) => SplashScreenCubit(APIRepository(
                              apiClient: APIClient(httpClient: http.Client()))),
                          child: SplashScreen(),
                        ),
                        type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft,
                        settings: settings);
                break;
              case 'create-account':
                return PageTransition(
                    child: BlocProvider(
                      create: (context) => CreateAccountScreenCubit(
                          APIRepository(
                              apiClient: APIClient(httpClient: http.Client()))),
                      child: CreateAccountScreen(),
                    ),
                    type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft,
                    settings: settings);
                break;
              case 'login':
                return PageTransition(
                        child: BlocProvider(
                          create: (context) => LoginScreenCubit(APIRepository(
                              apiClient: APIClient(httpClient: http.Client()))),
                          child: LoginScreen(),
                        ),
                        type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft,
                        settings: settings);
                break;
              default:
                 return null;
           },
        );
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you needed is to be able to navigate without getting the context from `Navigtor.of` as you want to handling deeplink, you need to use `navigatorKey` property, you can read the details [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/navigatorKey.html).

then your code will be look like this. [EDITED, I add where to add the navigator key on the material app]

```
void main() { ... }

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget { ... }

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {   
   Uri _latestUri;  
   Object _err;
   GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey();

  StreamSubscription _sub;

  @override   void initState() { ... }

  @override void dispose() { ... }

  void _handleIncomingLinks() {
     _sub = uriLinkStream.listen((Uri uri) {
      if (!mounted) return;
      print('got uri: $uri'); // printed: got uri: myapp://?key1=test
      setState(() {
        _latestUri = uri;
        _err = null;
      });

      // use the navigatorkey currentstate to navigate to the page you are intended to visit
      navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('login', (route) => false);
    }, onError: (Object err) { ... });

  @override Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
      return MaterialApp(
          ...
          navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
          ...
      );
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately your solution leads to the following error to be printed:  [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'pushNamedAndRemoveUntil' was called on null.

Comment: @RutgerHuijsmans did you register the key in MaterialApp(... , navigatorKey: ... , ...)?

Comment: This works and should be the answer. But it needs to show the addition of the navigator key

Comment: @RutgerHuijsmans, I have add more details on the answer, you need to place the navigatorKey in materail apps so the currentState value will not null

Answer (score 2):

Your deep link stream can be triggered before the build method, but you are not allowed to call `Navigator` at the time. So, you can fix it using `addPostFrameCallback` provided by `SchedulerBinding`:

#### [addPostFrameCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html)

> Schedule a callback for the end of this frame.
>
> Does not request a new frame.
>
> This callback is run during a frame, just after the persistent frame
> callbacks (which is when the main rendering pipeline has been
> flushed). If a frame is in progress and post-frame callbacks haven't
> been executed yet, then the registered callback is still executed
> during the frame. Otherwise, the registered callback is executed
> during the next frame.
>
> The callbacks are executed in the order in which they have been added.
>
> Post-frame callbacks cannot be unregistered. They are called exactly
> once.

```dart
...

void _handleIncomingLinks() {
  _sub = uriLinkStream.listen((Uri uri) {
    if (!mounted) return;
    print('got uri: $uri'); // printed: got uri: myapp://?key1=test
    setState(() {
      _latestUri = uri;
      _err = null;

      // Call your navigator inside addPostFrameCallback
      WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'login');
      });
    });
  }, onError: (Object err) {
    if (!mounted) return;
    print('got err: $err');
    setState(() {
      _latestUri = null;
      if (err is FormatException) {
        _err = err;
      } else {
        _err = null;
      }
    });
  });
}

...
```